# Sorting XML by subnode content

Tags: xml, xmllint

I have an XML document with the following structure

```
<movements status="1">
    <movement>
        <article>49-000003</article>
        <lot>0I0311</lot>
        <type>4</type>
        <date></date>
    </movement>
    <movement>
        <article>49-000013</article>
        <lot>0I0312</lot>
        <type>4</type>
        <date></date>
    </movement>
    <movement>
        <article>49-000001</article>
        <lot>0I0313</lot>
        <type>4</type>
        <date></date>
    </movement>
</movements>
```

How can I (using xmllint) sort it so the movement nodes are ordered by the article?

I need the output to be another XML file.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with xmllint; it can be easily done using xquery, but for that you will need to use xidel. If that's available, I can post an answer.

Comment: @JackFleeting  Thanks for the reply. Anything I can install on a Mac is available.
I suppose I can install it via Homebrew https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/xidel

Comment: @JackFleeting

iMac:~ sig$ xidel --version
Xidel 0.9.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this on your iMac and see if it works:

```
xidel  your_file.xml --xquery 'for $node in //movement order by $node/article return $node' --output-format xml
```

Comment: It kind of works. I can see the data sorted on my terminal. However, what I need is an xml file, like the original one with the node sorted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. For future readers: `--output-format xml >> new_file.xml` generates a new XML file.

Comment: Would it be possible to update the command so the subnodes are sorted alphabetically (article, date, lot, type)? See currently date is the last one. Thanks.

Comment: @Sig Probably, though I'll have to think it through. In any case, I believe it's best to post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) ([`tr` command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s02.html)), a simple XSLT should work...

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="article"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="movement">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command Line**

```
xmlstarlet tr test.xsl input.xml > output.xml
```

**Output** (output.xml)

```xml
<movements status="1">
   <movement>
      <article>49-000001</article>
      <date/>
      <lot>0I0313</lot>
      <type>4</type>
   </movement>
   <movement>
      <article>49-000003</article>
      <date/>
      <lot>0I0311</lot>
      <type>4</type>
   </movement>
   <movement>
      <article>49-000013</article>
      <date/>
      <lot>0I0312</lot>
      <type>4</type>
   </movement>
</movements>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Before I install all the depenedencies, can you please confirm for me the output is a sorted XML file? Cheers ...

Comment: @Sig - I’m not sure what you mean; the output is included in my answer and the `movement` elements are sorted by the values of the `article` elements.

Comment: I was wondering if the out would be a file or some text on my terminal. The `xidel` command works just fine for me without the need to create any additional XSLT file. Therefore, I have accepted that. Gain thanks for your time.

Comment: @Sig - You could redirect the output to a new file.

Comment: @Sig - I also saw your comment about sorting the the children of `movement`. I added that to the XSLT too.